# Passport-OpenID Connect configuration

Tags: node.js, passport.js, openid-connect

I'm trying to use [Passport-OpenID-Connect](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-openidconnect) to authenticate users on a web app.

Does anyone have a working example of this?

What package should I install?

```
$ npm install <passport-openid-connect>
```

How do I configure the strategy?

```
<OpenIDConnectStrategy> = require(<passport-openid-connect>).Strategy;

passport.use('...', new <OpenIDConnectStrategy>({
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

After a while I solved my own issue :)

```
$ npm install passport-openidconnect --save
```

then just require the lib in your passport config

```
var OICStrategy = require('passport-openidconnect').Strategy;
```